# Trouble accessing object within an object (for a for loop)

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, reference, javascript-objects

Essentially, I am trying to create a for loop which creates an object containing each candy's name and price.  I can access the inventory for a certain day with no problems using this

```
console.log(store3[4]['inventory sold'])

{ 'Dark Chocolate Crunchies': { cost: 4.29, quantity: 2 },
  'Mint Wafers': { cost: 1.09, quantity: 1 },
  'Peppermint Poppers': { cost: 2.38, quantity: 0 },
  'Peanut Butter Buttered Peanuts': { cost: 1.79, quantity: 2 },
  'Berry Bites': { cost: 7.89, quantity: 5 },
  'Caramel Twists': { cost: 0.5, quantity: 7 },
  'Banana Bunches': { cost: 4.53, quantity: 2 } }
```

As well as this

```
console.log(store3[4]['inventory sold']['Mint Wafers'])

{ cost: 1.09, quantity: 1 }
```

However, for a for loop, I need to use numerical values, and for some reason I get undefined when I try to run the prior command in this format.  Any suggestions?

```
console.log(store3[4]['inventory sold'][1])

undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.keys to get an array of keys only, then you forEach on this array and you will be abled to access every attribute of your objects.

```js
var datas = { 
  'Dark Chocolate Crunchies': { cost: 4.29, quantity: 2 },
  'Mint Wafers': { cost: 1.09, quantity: 1 },
  'Peppermint Poppers': { cost: 2.38, quantity: 0 },
  'Peanut Butter Buttered Peanuts': { cost: 1.79, quantity: 2 },
  'Berry Bites': { cost: 7.89, quantity: 5 },
  'Caramel Twists': { cost: 0.5, quantity: 7 },
  'Banana Bunches': { cost: 4.53, quantity: 2 }
}


Object.keys(datas).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key) ;
  console.log('cost',datas[key]['cost']) ;
  console.log('quantity',datas[key]['quantity']) ;
}) ;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is extremely helpful